# Difference between NULL DEFAULT NULL and DEFAULT NULL in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

Recently I faced a new problem in MySQL. I was about to create a new table with

`col1 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL`

(i.e. the column having the default `NULL` value), but on creation that gave me an error:

> Invalid default value for column

But when I tried `col1 TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL`, that table got created.

I want to know what is the difference between the above two syntaxes. I also faced this issue earlier too in some insert NULL values in column.

Can any one explain the cause of this problem, like is it a version specific issue or something else with MySQL?

Comment: If you have just `col1 timestamp null`, the `default null` can be omitted (at least according to the documentation). A non-nullable timestamp column has predefined special properties, but they are suppressed when you explicitly make the column nullable.

Answer (score 12):

The first `NULL` says that the column is *nullable*, i.e. accepts `NULL`. The second `NULL` (after `DEFAULT`) is the *default* value.

If you only have the default, but make the column reject nulls, then that default cannot be used.

(I was under the impression, though, that if you specify neither `NULL` nor `NOT NULL` that the column was nullable, so what you see is a bit confusing).

Comment: Can you explain If you only have the default, but make the column reject nulls, then that default cannot be used?

Comment: The default value must be a an acceptable value for the column. If you say that the column is not-nullable, you cannot put in `NULL`. So `NULL` cannot be used for the default value either.

Comment: Do you mean to say NULL can only be inserted if the column accepts NULL?

Comment: Yes, you can only insert NULL into a column that is nullable.